# Deploying react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react.js, and trying to deploy first beta app for which I used **webpack** to build it, now I have got **build.js** file. Now as per my understanding to deploy build.js I don't need to setup any thing in server, I just need to put following things

1. **index.html**
2. **build.js** pointed from inside index.html
3. **Resources and Styles** in their respective folder structure.

Am I going in right direction? Do I need to install npm/node etc on the server? or, just putting all the resources will work?

Thanks

Comment: Should Just Work™

Have you tried it and it's not working?  If so, please share details and logs

Comment: Yes, you'll need to install all the dependencies from npm.

Comment: Correct, it's all just static files, which can be served from any server, e.g. Apache, no need for node on the server, unless you want to use a node server like Express

Comment: Thanks for details, it seems working fine with all resources together.. thanks for confirming..

Comment: This question would be actually a good place to collect and explain the react building process ...

Answer (score 1):

As several commenters have mentioned, the method you outline is likely to "just work". A module bundler like Webpack is designed to take all your code and its dependencies and bundle them together in a set of files that can be executed directly in the runtime environment. For a simple client-side web application, the runtime environment is a web browser, so all you need is a way to serve the bundled files to the users' browsers.